# Unable to uninstall mysql 8.0 in macOS

Tags: mysql, macos, uninstallation

I need to install an older version of mysql (5.7) and remove current (8.0) from my system. I've tried multiple possible ways for the same but I can still output after running `mysql --version`

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for macos11.6 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

Ran below commands but no help:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
$ rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
$ sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*
```

I had installed by downloading the dmg image of the installer so removing using brew doesn't help. Any leads would help. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-mysql-on-mac

Comment: Yes tried that too. Couldn't find mysql in system preferences.
What worked for me was running `which mysql` command and removing all files I could find.